# How to calculate the energy and entropy content of an amount of substance?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, water

The Energy $U$ and the entropy $S$ are extensive state variables, so it makes sense to talk about the energy content and entropy content of a given amount of substance at standard conditions. Texbooks however rarely talk about content but only about *changes* in content.

How would one proceed in order to calculate the energy and entropy content of 1 liter of water at standard conditions? For the ideal gas, we have equations of state like the ideal gas law and the Sackur-Tetrode equation which allow us to perform similar calculations. Does this mean that we need the equations of state of liquid water? Is there such a thing? Or is there an easier way?

Also for the entropy content, is there an easy relationship to the heat capacity?

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching for the entropy $S(T,V,N)$ as a function of volume $V$, temperature $T$ and number of particles $N$, then you can find an easy relation with heat capacity:

$$ C_V = T \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_{V,N} $$

You can find this observation for example in the book of Landau (fifth volume §13), but almost in each book of thermodynamics.
It derives from the definition of $C_V$ and thermodynamic potentials:

$$ S =  - \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial T} \right)_{V,N}  =  - \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial T} \right)_{p,N}  =  - \left( \frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial T} \right)_{V,\mu} $$

For the explicit calculus of entropy you to find over of those potentials express in terms of their own thermodynamic variables: 
$$ F = F(V,T,N)$$
$$ \Omega = \Omega(V, T, \mu)$$
$$ G = G(p, T, N)$$

where $\mu$ is the chemical potential, $p$ there pressure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the relationship between the heat capacity and a change in entropy. Do you also know the answer to my main question? How much entropy does 1 liter of water contain?